# how to solve: Bundle' is deprecated. Use Android KTX version?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to pass data between fragments using navigation controller. in this documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-pass-data

it is said that I can send data using bundle, but when I type the code below:

```
var bundle = bundleOf("amount" to amount)
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.confirmationAction, bundle)
```

I have a message: Bundle' is deprecated. Use Android KTX version ?
[image]

what should I do ? I don't understand about that 'Use the Android KTX version'

Comment: It's a package which contains eXtensions for Kotlin: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx

Answer (score 4):

I finally find the answer,

so first add dependecy:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'
}
```

then import this:

```
import androidx.core.os.bundleOf
```

and finally the warning will dissapear

Answer (score 0):

I think it's requesting that top level function: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/os/package-summary#bundleOf%28kotlin.Pair%29

The import line should be something like: `import androidx.core.os.bundleOf`